# Creat in JQUERY a specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So let me explain. I have a exercise to do. (in jquery)

1 : create a button, when we click on it it will show a select with different option and a button "OK".

2: We select one, and then we click on "OK", its gonna create what we selected (number , name , password etc) but only 1 of each can be created (and with character restriction for mail, password etc etc).

3: a radio button put somewhere when wz click on it show a button submit.

(sorry for my English)

here what i did so far.

EDIT : (forgot the question duh) So how my question is how can I creat only 1 of each when I click on OK (name, password ect )

EDIT 2 : Also how can I add some regex to restrict number of characters for exemple ? Should I use some var with some function ?

HTML~

```
<button type="button" id="button">Add un champ</button>

<select style="display:none" id="choix">
    <option value="">--Choisir--</option>
    <option value="mail">Email</option>
    <option value="nom">Nom</option>
    <option value="password">password</option>
    <option value="number">number</option>
</select>


<button style="display:none" type="button" id="OK">OK</button>

<form>

    <div id="div">

    </div>


</form>
```

JS~

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#choix , #OK").toggle();
    });
    $("#choix").change(function() { // lorsqu'on change de valeur dans la liste
    var valeur = $(this).val(); // valeur sélectionnée

        if(valeur != '') { 
            if( valeur == 'mail') { 

                $('#div').append('<p>Mail</p> <input type="text" />');
            }
            else if(valeur == 'nom') {
                $('#div').append('<p>nom</p> <input type="text" />');
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So.... what is your question ?

Comment: Yeah if forgot to put it. I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#choix , #OK").toggle();
    });
    $('#OK').click(function(){
      var valeur = $('#choix').val();

        if(valeur != '' && !checkIfExists(valeur)) { 
            switch(valeur) {
                case "mail":
                    $('#div').append('<p>' + valeur + '</p><input type="text" />');
                    break;
                case "nom":
                    $('#div').append('<p>' + valeur + '</p><input type="text" />');
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});

function checkIfExists(type){
  if($(document).find('p:contains("' + type + '")').length > 0){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">Add un champ</button>

<select style="display:none" id="choix">
    <option value="">--Choisir--</option>
    <option value="mail">Email</option>
    <option value="nom">Nom</option>
    <option value="password">password</option>
    <option value="number">number</option>
</select>


<button style="display:none" type="button" id="OK">OK</button>

<form>

    <div id="div">

    </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Working great ! Also is that possible to add some regex (mail ect ) ? With a var or something ?

Comment: @BrescazGuillaume maybe you can better ask this as a new question, because it a whole new one.

Answer (score 0):

> So how my question is how can I creat only 1 of each when I click on OK (name, password ect )

As per your question you have to bind an event on the OK button and i just did some changes to simplify your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#choix , #OK").toggle();
  });
  $("#OK").click(function() {
    var $choix = $('#choix');
    var $txt = $choix.find(':selected').text();
    if ($choix.val() != '') {
      $('#div').append('<p>' + $txt + '</p> <input type="' + $choix.val() + '" />');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">Add un champ</button>
<select style="display:none" id="choix">
    <option value="">--Choisir--</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="nom">Nom</option>
    <option value="password">Password</option>
    <option value="number">Number</option>
</select>
<button style="display:none" type="button" id="OK">OK</button>

<form>
  <div id="div">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks ! But saddly we can create infinite input text ^^